# Why does 'adb.exe devices' not show my phone?

Tags: adb

I have USB Debugging & File Transfer both enabled on my phone (Blackview A80Pro) and I have installed the USB driver for my phone as recommended by Blackview. But though 'adb.exe version' shows the version, 'adb devices' does not show my phone on Windows 10. Interestingly, Ubuntu 20.04 does see my phone using a Linux version of adb!

Comment: Your question is off-topic here. some hints for windows https://superuser.com/q/1656702 https://superuser.com/q/1669444

Comment: If it works on Linux you might have installed the Windows ADB driver on the wrong device. Usually there should be three devices coming from an Android phone: first the USB compound device, second the regular MTP device for file access and last the adb USB device.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does 'adb.exe devices' not see my phone on Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1708725/why-does-adb-exe-devices-not-see-my-phone-on-windows-10)